# Migrate from Sqlite to CoreData

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, core-data

I have an application in which I am using Sqlite database till now. I want to upgrade application and deliver core data instead of Sqlite. I need to migrated existing sqlite db data to new core data db.

I am aware of the manual way in which I need to read data from sqlite DB and write it back to core data db once `NSManagedObjectContext` get ready for use.

I am looking for some automated way. Is there any way by which I can get rid of manual way and save my existing data from sqlite db to new core data db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Core Data's FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH29-SW3):

> How do I use my existing SQLite database with Core Data?
>
> You do not, unless you import your existing SQLite database into a Core Data store. Although Core Data supports SQLite as one of its persistent store types, the database format is private. You cannot create a SQLite database using the native SQLite API and use it directly with Core Data. If you have an existing SQLite database, you need to import it into a Core Data store. In addition, do not manipulate an existing Core Data-created SQLite store using the native SQLite API.

You have to automate this yourself.